# C# dynamic ProgressBar

Tags: c#, progress-bar

My winform has a progress bar which should increase based on the number of files the program is processing. it works fine on one box (win xp)  but not the other(winserver 2008).  The bar is not filled fully by the time the process ends. Both have the same .net framework 3.5

```
private void data_process()
    {
        int progress_num = (100/checkedListBox1.Items.Count);
        .......
         progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + progress_num;}
```

do you know why? and do you have better solution?

------this is the new code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No file is selected", "Warning");

        }

        else
        {
            if ((region != null) && (venue != null) && (lhversion != null) && (release_version != null) && (desc != null))
            {
                progressBar1.Maximum = checkedListBox1.Items.Count + 3;
                progressBar1.Step = 1;
                //progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 10;
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                login();
                //progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 10;
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                data_process();
                //progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 10;
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
                if (user_in == true)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue; 
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("Done");
                }
            }

 private void data_process()
 {
            string line;
            //int progress_num = (70/checkedListBox1.Items.Count);

            foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) // for each selected file
            {
                  ...
                  progressBar1.PerformStep();
            }
}
```

Comment: Well, "what doesn't work fine"? Make sure that you are "yielding" control back to the UI so it can actually react to events and draw stuff. (Long running tasks are often run on another thread, say using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which supports reporting progress.)

Comment: The bar is not filled fully by the time the process ends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to use the native command to increment the progress bar without calculating the increment
(what happens when the items are > 100?)

```
progressBar1.Maximum = checkedListBox1.Items.Count;
progressBar1.Step = 1;
...
progressBar1.PerformStep();
```

Comment: I thought 100 is to represent 100%. so if you have 5 files , everytime you are done with a file the bar increases by 20%. is it not ??

Comment: Yes, Maximum will be 5 so 1 step will draw a fifth of your progress bar width. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx)

Comment: It seems to me that you are losing progress information in your code.  For example, if you have 75 items in your list, you would end up with an increment value of 1.33333.  Int will round this to 1, so you are losing one third of a progress item on every update in this example.  This may be leading to your bar not being "filled up" when the process is completed.

Comment: @Chris. Using Steve's logic I should not having int problem. It still not working.

Comment: progressBar1.Maximum = checkedListBox1.Items.Count + 3;
progressBar1.Step = 1;
progressBar1.PerformStep();
login();
progressBar1.PerformStep();
data_process();
progressBar1.PerformStep();

Comment: then inside data_process() I have progressBar1.PerformStep();

Comment: the idea is it will always have 3+N. N is the number of files

Comment: Just to see if it is a refresh problem. After the last PerformStep() add a `progressBar1.Refresh();` and one `Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: Ah, you set the Maximum to the Items.Count, but you loop on checkeditems

Comment: @Steve, you are DA MAN! That's it. It works fine now. what throw me off is it worked ok on one box but not the other. same number of files. crazy. I dont have explanation

Comment: Glad to be of help @JohnRyann.